# Using GatherBy with a DataSet's header designation instead of First

Tags: dataset, gathering, headers-footers

Using the code, where ds is data formatted into a Dataset

```
GroupBy[ds, First] // TableForm
```

I get a table that I wanted, but I was wondering if I could somehow use the header of my dataset to designate which column to group by.

I just want to guard against a file generating some data and the first column not being the one I want to group my data by.

If we call the name of the column "name",  I would like to do something to the tune of

```
GroupBy[ds, name] // TableForm
```

Comment: `ds[GroupBy[#name&]]` or `GroupBy[#name&][ds]` or `GroupBy[ds, #name&]`?

Comment: Ahh ds[GroupBy[#name&]] works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ds[GroupBy[#name&]] (* or *)
GroupBy[#name&][ds] (* or *)
GroupBy[ds, #name&]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another form that may be a bit easier to work with than the [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) form in kguler's answer:

```
ds = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]

ds[GroupBy["b"]]
```

[image]

You could also use [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html):

```
ds ~GroupBy~ Extract["b"]
```

In either case if the name is not a string add [`Key`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html).

Comment: Ah I see, yes the headers are strings, ds[GroupBy[Key["b"]]] worked as well.  Thanks for the syntax lesson Mr.Wizard!...somehow this eluded me in the mathematica documentation center definition for GroupBy

Comment: Ahh it does say that too, albeit not as clearly, I must have been reading too fast